# UISegmentedControl will not allow me to edit the selected colour

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

So I've got a bit of code which I would expect to set the selected colour of a segmented controller to what I ask, and the unselected segments to another colour, see the below:

```
    //normal segment
NSDictionary *normalAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rok" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont,
                                  [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:75.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                  [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                  nil];//[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:  [UIColor redColor]forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rok" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont,
                                    [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                    nil] ;//[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:  [UIColor redColor]forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

So what am I doing wrong? It's really frustrating that to directly change the colour of the selected segment is so difficult! I'm tempted to just use a row of buttons!

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: change UISegmentedControl selected segment color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in value changed event of your UISegmentedControl:

```
 for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++) 
 {
   if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] ) 
   {               
     UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor redColor]; //your requiremnent color here
     [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
     break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a lot for that. How would I get it to make this colour adjustment on load? As in, if I put that code in the unload method, it hasn't changed the index selected yet so bio update is made - ideally this tint on the selected segment needs to apply when first loaded. Furthermore I notice that it holds the red colour when you click on another element, how do you make the adjustment back to the previous colour selection? Or do you have to explicitly set it as a new colour to revert the changes made?